# Adding to a list in a Parallel.ForEach loop in a threadsafe manner

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a bit of code that works like this on a list of obj objects called ListofObjects:

```
List<SomeObject> NewListofObjects<SomeObject>();

Parallel.ForEach(ListofObjects, obj =>

//Do some operations here on obj to get a newobj

NewListofObjects.Add(newobj);

);
```

Now I am out of the Parallel.ForEach loop, and I want to do an operation on NewListofObjects. However, I get this error when I try to: **"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".**

Is this because my NewListofObjects.Add(newobj) method is not threadsafe? If so, how can I make it threadsafe?

Comment: what operations are you doing inside(from obj to get to newobj)?

Comment: A long mess of operations that would be difficult to describe... but they all are local variables created within each iteration of the object list. You're correct in asking this though... I haven't ruled out that all of the operations I am doing on the object might also be the root cause of this specific issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is this because my `NewListofObjects.Add(newobj)` method is not threadsafe?

Correct. It is not threadsafe.

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

That's from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) referring to `List<T>` (scroll to the section titled "Thread Safety").

> If so, how can I make it threadsafe?

Use a concurrent collection, like [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx). Note that you lose the ability to keep track of the order that items were inserted.

Comment: Fortunately for me the order of the items does not matter in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might be able to use a ConcurrentBag for processing then do something like `var list = bag.OrderBy(p => p.SomeCondition).ToList();` That might perform better than locking around every list add.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `locking` block like the following code to insert items into your list in a thread-safe manner.

```
var sync = new object();
var myNewList = new List<SomeObject>();
Parallel.ForEach(myListOfSomethings, a =>
    {
        // Some other code...
        var someObj = new SomeObject();
        // More other code...
        lock(sync)
        {
            myNewList.Add(someObj);
        }
        // Even more code...
    });
```

Comment: I wish I could mark multiple answers as correct as this would solve the issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! This solution preserves the order of the items being added too, but in your case it works out either way. Jason's method has better performance.

Comment: Is there any reason not to lock myNewList instead?

Comment: You could definitely lock on 'myNewList' directly rather than having a secondary object variable, as long as you can guarantee no other code (like a public method that client code can access) will access the same object while it is locked. The client app would then be blocked entirely while waiting for the list object to be unlocked. That can have issues as well.

Comment: wouldn't the usage of "lock" defeat the purpose of Parallel.ForEach()?

Comment: @wenn22 that is a good point. It is an issue if the lock is wrapped around a very time consuming portion of the delegate. It's important to design the logic to release the lock as soon as possible around the thread-unsafe resource (the list object here).

Comment: Thanks, I spent tens of hours adapting my code (full of nested loops) hoping to make foreach.parallel work in separate TASK using await and wasting tons of hours unnecessarily (it didn't fit for several reasons) and the code becomes increasingly incomprehensible .. your solution is rather direct and elegant.
One note:
var sync = new object();

It doesn't make much sense, I would have called it "tagThread" , if I'm not mistaken, it's a variable that only serves the system to get the thread it belongs to, it doesn't read and doesn't use its content.

Comment: @Bronz - thanks! yes, the `sync` variable is simply there for locking on a section of code that could be accessed by multiple threads. Under the hood, the `lock` statement does some fancy code generation to make sure that only one thread accesses that code block at a time, and it needs a memory location to do that with.

You could definitely call the variable anything you wanted. I've just seen many examples use the term `sync` for operations like this.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework 4 introduces the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace, which includes several collection classes that are both thread-safe and scalable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

```
BlockingCollection<int>[] sourceArrays = new BlockingCollection<int>[5];
for (int i = 0; i < sourceArrays.Length; i++)
    sourceArrays[i] = new BlockingCollection<int>(500);
Parallel.For(0, sourceArrays.Length * 500, (j) =>
{
    int k = BlockingCollection<int>.TryAddToAny(sourceArrays, j);
    if (k >= 0)
        Console.WriteLine("added {0} to source data", j);
});
```