# Are all threads killed after a Parallel.ForEach loop terminates?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have some code that takes a list of objects named obj and converts them to new objects, newobj, storing them in a list.

> ```
> List<SomeObject> NewListofObjects<SomeObject>();
> var addListLock = new object();
>
> Parallel.ForEach(ListofObjects, obj =>
>
> //Do some operations here on obj to get a newobj
>
> lock (addListLock) 
> {  
> NewListofObjects.Add(newobj);                  
> }
>
> ); 
>
> if (NewListofObjectsCount == 2)
> {
> CombineNewObjs(NewListofObjects[0], NewListofObjects[1]);
> }
> ```

The code creates the new objects and stores them in the list just fine. But when I get to CombineNewObjs (which is outside of the Parallel.ForEach loop), I get this error: **"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".**

The program runs fine if I run it in non-parallel sequence, and it does everything correctly up to CombineNewObjs. Could the problem be that I have to somehow release my list from threading so that I can execute the method on it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  Is this question different than [your last one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17416357/634824)?  They look almost identical.  And to assist us in helping you, please make sure the code you post compiles.  This doesn't.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the welcome! Yes, this question refers to the structure of a Parallel.ForEach, asking whether all threads are killed after the loop terminates, or whether special steps must be taken after the termination to access resources created from within the loop. My previous question referred to whether lists themselves were inherently thread safe.

Unfortunately my code requires a GIS SDK to compile, so most users here will be unable to compile it without the requisite software installed. This is why I have chosen to deal in simple abstractions instead of posting my actual code.

Comment: Please edit your question/title with your comment. Right now post have nothing to do with above comments.

Comment: In general, if your example code can't reproduce the issue, it will be very difficult to provide an answer (unless the problem is glaringly obvious).  From our position, all we have is what you provided.  At least try to fix the syntax errors and try not to use custom methods that you haven't provided details about.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm looking to gain a greater understanding of parallelism in general, so what I will do is flag this question for moderator deletion and repost it as a more conceptual question with no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could the problem be that I have to somehow release my list from threading so that I can execute the method on it?

No, that's not the problem. The problem is likely to be in the code you didn't show. It's possible that `Parallel.ForEach()` just made the problem visible. Without knowing more about your code, it's impossible to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The list object is not thread safe.  Using a lock to protect it inside of a paralle.foreach make no sense.  There are thread safe collections such as [blocking collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) but they have different semantics.

Comment: Using a lock like this is safe and makes perfect sense, assuming the converting operation takes a long time.

Comment: I didn't see that it was two lists I thought he was locking on the same list he was iterating if there are two lists this has some value but is still not what I would call a good idiom.  Creating Tasks that produce then tasks that add the items could be a better want to go